# Permissions when updating an app

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing an Android application and I have uploaded it to Google Play. When installing the application request for the camera, storage, etc. But when doing an update, it asks me again about the permission again. 
Example camera permission:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void requestCameraPermission() {
    Log.w(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission");

    final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
        return;
    }
```

Is there any way to avoid this?? Perhaps by code I can ask if the app is updating, that you do not ask for them again.

Comment: are you sure you are not uninstalling the app before install?

Comment: I only update the app, without uninstalling it. And it asks me again about the permissions.